# Ignore blank spaces in code block with changes using git diff

Tags: git, git-diff

I am trying to only get lines with changes using git diff. However, it is still counting blank lines in a code block with changes.

Here is my git diff command:

```
git diff --ignore-all-space --ignore-blank-lines --numstat HEAD
```

Example original code:

```
public void myCodeChange() {
    String s = "original"
    return s;
}
```

Example changed code:

```
public void myCodeChange() {
    String s = "changes"

    return s;
}
```

Here is what the diff looks like:

```
 public void myCodeChange() {
-     String s = "original"
+    String s = "changes"
+
     return s;
 }
```

I expect this to be 1 line added when running my git diff, however it is returning 2 lines added. Is there a way to make it not count that blank line?

Comment: Include the diff that you observe.

Comment: Just added the diff. It shows 2 additions, even though one of the lines is a blank line.

Comment: What happens if you use `--ignore-space-change`?

Comment: Same result as in the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the [documentation of --ignore-blank-lines](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---ignore-blank-lines):

> Ignore changes whose lines are all blank.

The text is pretty clear that the option causes changes to be ignored only when they consist *only* of changes in blank lines.

I do not know of a way to not count the added blank line in your example text

Comment: Yeah it doesn't seem like it is possible with the `git diff` options sadly.